# Which definition is better for performance?

Tags: flutter

I was wondering about some performance tips for flutter.

Here is my question.

I have `ThemeService` class. If I want to set my primary color, I use it inside `build` method like this:

```
...
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final Color primary = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
    
        return Container(
            color:secondary
            );
```

But I have so many pages. So, if I have put this `color` variable inside some dart file like this.

```
primary(BuildContext context) => Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
```

Therefore, whenever I need this color, I can call it from anywhere like this (must be in the build method because of BuildContext):

```
...
 color: primary(context),
...
```

Which alternative is better?

I know Flutter recommends us to separate widgets as class, but in this situation, I can't use class.

Any help will be appreciated.